# Click listener on image broken in Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I run this code to make a button then add it to a GridLayout.

```
private Image makeButton(String text) {
    final Image imageButton = new Image(text);
    imageButton.setIcon(new ExternalResource("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-inspired-mac-icon-set/128/_app_store_128.png"));
    imageButton.addClickListener(new MouseEvents.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void click(MouseEvents.ClickEvent event) {
            Notification.show("Hello World");
        }
    });
    return imageButton;
}
```

However the click event is never called. Any idea how/why this could happen?

Comment: Why do you want to use an image to create a button and not the button component itself?

Comment: where do you click?  if i put the resource as the resource fro the image (and not like the icon) the click works fine for me (7.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setSource()` instead of `setIcon()`.